# How can I view and copy an email address in a message header within iOS' Mail.app?

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email

If I reply-to-all on an inbound message with multiple recipients within iOS' Mail.app, I can't view or move/copy the email address of any recipients - I can only view the a 'bubble' which contains their name.

Curious if there is a way to view the actual email address **while composing**, and ideally, copy the address (in case I wanted to move it from the TO: field to the CC: field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 4.2 at least, you can tap on the bubble to see the email address, then press and hold on the email address.  A copy option will appear above it.

Comment: If the address is found in contacts the corresponding contact would be shown (with all data). The email address used in that given email is highlightes in blue.

Comment: I believe that is only when looking at an existing message - not when you are in the compose function, which is the basis of my question.  Thanks

Comment: You have to double tap to view the address, at least in iOS5, but you can then view and copy it.

Answer (score 2):

Click on "forward". Then you can see all the headers   Then click cancel to go back to the email.

Answer (score 0):

Press an address bubble for half a second or so until it puffs up a bit then drag it to the To or Cc field to copy it over. Tap to select the name bubble, then tap the now highlighted bubble again to reveal the address.